# Underline inside of enumerate and align

Tags: math-mode, equations, enumerate, syntax, underline

MAIN QUESTION! This is my first question on here so bear with me. I would like to underline my last line of code where it says underline. I have tried to do so as you can see below, but I keep getting an error. I have looked at other posts, but they do not work for my situation as the users are not inside of enumerate or aligned.

For a bonus, I would also like to do the following

1 Align all numbers, operators, variables, andd insert blank spaces for variables not displayed. As shown in the second image below.

2 I would like to have the word solution and the following equations closer to the left because they appear too far to the right.

3 I would like to have a column for each question and/or answer similar to the format shown in the second image below.

4 I would also like to know how I can bring the word solution down without needing to put so many backslashes as shown below.

5 I cannot get the hyphen to appear where it shows exercises 1-4 when I compile my code.

Please note that I am a code minimalist as you can see, aha! So, if it is possible to code in the desired format using a small amount of code that would be much appreciated.

CODE FOR MAIN QUESTION

```
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    $
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      x_1+5x_2&= 7 \\ 
    -2x_1-7x_2&=-5 \\
    \end{aligned} \\\\\\
    \textbf{Solution:} \\\\
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      x_1+5x_2&=7  \\
    -2x_1-7x_2&=-5 \\\\
    2(x_1 +5x_2&=7) & \text{Replacement Eq. 2}\\
    \underline{+-2x_1-7x_2&=-5}
    \end{aligned}
    $
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

[image: IMAGE FOR ALL QUESTIONS EXCEPT Q1 & Q3]

[image: IMAGE FOR Q1 & Q3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The issue is not enumerate, nor aligned, but the fact that you want to underline some piece that contains an `&`. You can solve this issue by saying `\underline{+-2x_1-7x_2}&\underline{=-5\vphantom{x_1}}`. The `\vphantom` is just there to make sure that the underline is on the same level on both sides of the `&`.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Follow the suggestions of the marmot, and 2) I like the red-black style :).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for correcting my silly misspellings. Didn't know people could do that.

Comment: @manooooh thanks! I use overleaf v1 night style. v2 does not havev this style.

Comment: As Zarko answered, one problem per question works best on this site.  The `-` disappears because you copy and pasted an en-dash from somewhere else instead of typing `-` on your keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- please one problem per question ...
- your mwe is not complete and it produce different result from your illustration of problem
- main problem can be solved by use of `\array` instead of the `aligned` math environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$
\begin{array}[t]{rl}
  x_1+5x_2&= 7 \\   \hline
-2x_1-7x_2&=-5 \\   \hline
\end{array}
$

\bigskip
\textbf{Solution:}
$
\begin{array}[t]{rll}
  x_1+5x_2  &=7  &  \\
-2x_1-7x_2  &=-5 &  \\
2(x_1 +5x_2 &=7) & \qquad\text{Replacement Eq. 2}\\
\pm 2x_1-7x_2&=-5 &    \\   \cline{1-2}
\end{array}
$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

- array option `[t]` align array first row with text row where array is placed(without option the vertical center of array is aligned and with option `[b]` is aligne bottom array row
- `cline{1-2}˛draw line from start of first column to end of the second column
- command `\pm` (plus minus) write symbol `+` over `-`
- i suggest you to read some introductory texts about latex, for example [The Not so short Introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) or for tables in math as are [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) and [LaTeX/Mathematics](http://LaTeX/Mathematics)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and nice tips for using stack exchange! Since I am fairly new to LaTeX, some of what you have done I did not understand. What is \cline, connect line? Also, what is \pm? Also, I found [t] online but I do not know what that means. Can you explain it? Thanks again @Zarko